# Creating a variable with an onTap navigator flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

This will be a lot of explaining but i hope someone will be able to help.

Currently i have search button on my appbar that, when pressed, covers over my appbar title with a textfield

The normal appbar title is an image and i am adding functionality that when pressed, it brings you to the home screen.  This is were it gets tricky, because i need to use this line of code to accomplish just that

```
new InkWell (
    child: Image.asset(
      'images/logoGrey.png',
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              LandingPage(),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

so i set that to a variable like so

```
class _ControlsPageState extends State<ControlsPage> {
  Widget appBarTitle = new InkWell (
    child: Image.asset(
      'images/logoGrey.png',
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              LandingPage(),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

The reason i have this variable is so that i can change the state of the appbar(title) to a textfield when i click on the search button and back to the image when i close out.

but this wont work (error on "context") seeing as though this line of code below can only be used under "Widget build(BuildContext context)" and not in my class....

```
onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              LandingPage(),
        ),
      );
    },
```

The bottom line is i need my appbar title to be a callback to the variable "appBarTitle", and the variable gets an error on "context", is there anyway i can make this work?

here is the appbar code in case it helps

```
appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: appBarTitle ,
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: actionIcon,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                    this.actionIcon =
                        new Icon(Icons.close, color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey);
                    this.appBarTitle = new TextField(
                      onSubmitted: (String str) {
                        setState(() {
                          result = str;
                        });
                        controller.text = "";
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ControlSearchPage(
                                search: result, title: "${widget.title}"),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon:
                              new Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey),
                          hintText: "Search...",
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey)),
                    );
                  } else {
                    this.actionIcon =
                        new Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey);
                    this.appBarTitle = new InkWell (
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'images/logoGrey.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                LandingPage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

any comments will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change appBarTitle to be a method that can generate the widget on state change rather than saving it to a variable. This way, you can ensure that it will only be generated when `context` is available.

```
// Define a bool to hold the current search state
bool _isSearching = false;

...

// In your build method
appBar: AppBar(
  iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  centerTitle: true,
  title: _buildAppBarTitle(),
  actions: <Widget>[
    new IconButton(
      icon: _isSearching
        ? new Icon(Icons.close, color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey)
        : new Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() => _isSearching = !_isSearching);
      },
    ),
  ],
),

...

// Define a separate method to build the appBarTitle
Widget _buildAppBarTitle() {
  if (_isSearching) {
    return new TextField(
      onSubmitted: (String str) {
        setState(() {
          result = str;
        });
        controller.text = "";
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ControlSearchPage(
                search: result, title: "${widget.title}"),
          ),
        );
      },
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon:
              new Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey),
          hintText: "Search...",
          hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey)),
    );
  } else {
    return new InkWell (
      child: Image.asset(
        'images/logoGrey.png',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                LandingPage(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```